# Libgdx virtual width and height

Tags: java, libgdx, screen-resolution

I am following this tutorial: http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=25685.new and using virtual widths and heights.

My requirements are:

1. Background image should fill the entire screen
2. Aspect ratio of game assets should be preserved : My virtual width, height are: 800,600. One of the game assets has initial virtual position: 450,20, so I set:

   ```
   playerSprite.setPosition(450, 20);//I assume (450,20) would be virtual
   ```

The problem is that player (game asset) is not visible when I set my window size to 200X200 through main function. I thought assets (size and positions) would automatically scale preserving aspect ratios. However, when I set my screen size to 800X600 and then resized it to 200X200 (manually) then the assets were scaled and positioned properly. I do not what is the difference between setting 200X200 in the main function vs. resizing bigger window to 200X200 afterwards.

**My render function:**

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
//Stretch background to cover the entire screen
if(backgroundTR!=null){
//Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    batch.begin();
batch.draw(backgroundTR, 0, 0,screenWidth,screenHeight);
batch.end();
}

//Preserve aspect ratios of assets as per the tutorial
orthographicCamera.update();
orthographicCamera.apply(Gdx.gl10);
Gdx.gl.glViewport((int)viewport.x, (int)viewport.y, (int)viewport.width, (int)viewport.height);

batch.begin();
batch.draw(titleTR,160f,450f);
    //batch.draw(playerTR,450f,20f);
playerSprite.draw(batch);
batch.end();
```

The background is not filled either. Any help?

Comment: Please take a look at the libgdx wiki this isnt needed anymore since the stage do have the possebility to hold the resolution and aspect ratio! http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d#Viewport

So the tutorial is outdate

Comment: Ok. But I solved my problem! I used one class to draw background (stretching it full screen). I extended that class and used concept of virtual view ports to keep the aspect ratio of assets. But I will have a look at "stage".

Comment: The whole stuff about the resizing isnt needed anymore so you will have way less problems and also less problems with the touchpoints and so on. You even do not need to handle a camera anymore if you'd like to